# Logs with stack traces

Tags: spring-boot, logging, splunk, spring-cloud-sleuth

I work on service which is based on spring boot 2 , for tracing logs I use spring sleuth and splunk for collecting logs itself. 
But if there are stack traces in logs it looks weird and stack traces are not marked with tracedID.

I have 2 questions:
1. Should I exclude stack traces from production logs at all ?
2. Or how can I marked stack traces with traceID?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is quite broad and does not relates directly to a programming issue. Maybe you can find better help on serverfault

Comment: Stacktraces should have trace ids. Most likely you parse multiline logs in an invalid manner. Please ensure that you're splunk configuration is set properly

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't exclude them in my opinion. Production isn't bug free, so stacktraces might be the only option to detect sources of potential issues. If you want you could move them to separate file.
2. It depends on exception source, I found [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/656) and it looks like Sleuth works fine only within classes in Spring Context scope.

Comment: What do you think about filtering or cutting stack trace somehow? In the most cases we don’t need whole stack to find the problem , but we need root exception or exception message.

Comment: You can't be sure about it. My advice is to always log full stackstraces and if they annoy you - work on exception handling for them. I mean - limit the exception logging - sure, but do it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Better still, fix the code to avoid throwing so many exceptions in the 1st place.  Avoid flow control via `throw` / `catch`.  You should log *all* exceptions and almost all with the full stack trace at least once.

If your logs are too noisy it is because your code is throwing too many exceptions.  In this case, it is time to examine your approach to error handling.   If your code has many `try` / `catch` blocks, think about if you can actually recover from the exceptions thrown and how you identify the context when logging.